# Trying to replace all spaces with + in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace all spaces with +'s in a string, but after I do the preg_replace(), I get a blank string as the result.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
$query = "hello world";
$formattedQuery = preg_replace('\s', '+', $query);
echo "formatted Query is: ".$formattedQuery;
/* output should be hello+world, but I am getting nothing / blank string outputted */
```

Comment: You could just use `$formattedQuery = str_replace(' ', '+', $query);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use `str_replace()`

```
$query = "hello world";
$formattedQuery = str_replace(' ', '+', $query);
echo "formatted Query is: ".$formattedQuery;
```

If your insist on using `preg_replace()` then turn the first parameter into a regular expression:

```
$query = "hello world";
$formattedQuery = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $query);
echo "formatted Query is: ".$formattedQuery;
```

Comment: Good call - for simple "replace x with y" situations, don't waste processing on a regex.  Real pattern matching calls for the regular expression functions.  str_replace() is the right solution here.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with data over URL what you actually need is `urlencode` not replace spaces

```
$query = "hello world";
echo urlencode($query);
```

If Not then you can use

```
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', "+", $query);
```

Output

```
hello+world
```

Answer (score 1):

For preg_replace, try:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

$formattedQuery = preg_replace('/\s/', '+', $query);